# What is the Numbers equivalent of F2 in Excel?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, editing, iwork-numbers

What is the Numbers equivalent of F2 (edit cell) in Excel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>